# What does くらいちゃんと mean here?

Tags: particles, expressions, adverbs, suffixes

「なによそれー！幼馴染にくらいちゃんと悩みは相談しなさい！」

What does くらい modify? ちゃんと has the opposite meaning.

Also, I can replace は with を here, can't I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This くらい means "at least", and it is associated with 幼馴染に, not ちゃんと.

- [Understanding くらい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34126/5010)
- [Does でも mean "but" in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86037/5010)

> **幼馴染にくらい**ちゃんと悩みは相談しなさい！
> You should talk about your problems **at least to your childhood friend**!

And yes, you can replace 悩みは to 悩みを.

Comment: Is 幼馴染くらいに right too? Does ちゃんと mean "properly" here?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi No, 幼馴染くらいに would mean "to your childhood friend *or something*". Yes, ちゃんと is "properly".